# Mysql: Inserting Current TimeStamp with microseconds Precision

Tags: php, mysql

As given here, We can insert fractional Seconds:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

If  Execute this Query
`CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6));`
and Insert using NOW() I GET `2015-09-18 20:11:40.000000` in database.

Further if I set  Attribute with DATETIME `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it does not store the fractional Seconds.

How can i save Fractional Seconds in MYSQL? i don't want to insert it i want the Current TimeStamp or something like NOW()?
What Query can be used to Insert the Timestamp?

Further can php be used if there is no function available in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with the `sysdate()` function instead of `NOW()`:

```
SELECT sysdate(6);
```

Reason simply is that `NOW()` is based on a TIMESTAMP which only resolves to seconds.